# How to resolve- xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: junk after document element- even after having single root element

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, xmltodict

my xml structure has one single root element. but

`xmltodict.parse(request)` 
is giving me this error- xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: junk after document element.

Although it does run successfully sometimes, and sometimes throws the error. The XML file I'm using is same everytime.
I've tried using other xml to json/dict parsers and still getting same issue.

Please help me figure out how to fix this.

xml data format-

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<results preview='0'>
<meta>
<fieldOrder>
<field>attrs.env</field>
<field>db</field>
<field>type</field>
<field>StartTime</field>
<field>EndTime</field>
<field>status</field>
<field>info_max_time</field>
<field>info_min_time</field>
<field>info_search_time</field>
<field>info_sid</field>
</fieldOrder>
</meta>
</results>
```

I've stored this in a variable requests. Getting the error while running:

`xmltodict.parse(request)`

Comment: Hi @mzjn I've added my xml document

Comment: I don't know how to reproduce the problem. There is no error in the XML in the question. How is the `requests` variable created? Why is the question tagged with "fast-xml-parser"?

Comment: I'm getting it from a http post request

Comment: OK, but you have still not explained how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: If the error is not consistent, my suspicions would fall on the HTTP access returning invalid XML on some occasions for some reason.

Comment: when you face the exception - save the xml to disk. share the xml here.